# How do I embed a form within a modal?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

With Craft Commerce, users have the ability to save, edit and delete addresses.

At present, if a user wants to add or edit an address, they are taken to a separate page. I want to know how I can embed a new address form (or indeed one with an existing address) into a modal on the same page.

This is the default code that displays the list of saved addresses and an 'Edit' link:

```
{% if craft.commerce.customer.addresses %}
  {% for address in craft.commerce.customer.addresses %}
    <div class="block p3">
      <a class="u-pull-right" href="/commerce/customer/addresses/edit?addressId={{ address.id }}">Edit</a>
      <form style="position:absolute;" method="POST">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/customerAddresses/delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ address.id }}"/>
        <input type="submit" class="button button-outline" value="x"/>
      </form>
      {% include 'commerce/_includes/address' with {'address': address} %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <p>You currently have no addresses saved. Go ahead and add one.</p>
{% endif %}
```

This is the code for the modal dialog:

```
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
  <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
  [CODE HERE]
</div>
```

....which is triggered by:

```
<a data-remodal-target="modal">Call the modal with data-remodal-id="modal"</a>
```

How do I go about embedding the address form into a modal? So that when a user clicks 'edit' or 'Add' a modal dialog appears with the relevant content?

Help would be much appreciated as this is a little beyond me.